# Source in reactive content Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to split my app into smaller peaces for better handling.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
source("onLoad.R", local = TRUE)

  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

     sourceRecursive("/.../")

 })
```

**sourceRecursive**

```
#check folder and all subfolders for .R files
#source() them! 
sourceRecursive <- function(path) {
      dirs <- list.dirs()
      files <- dir(pattern = "^.*[Rr]$", include.dirs = FALSE)
      for (f in files)
          source(f)
      for (d in dirs)
          sourceRecursive(d)
 }
```

**example file I try to source. file.R**

```
output$myChoices <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = 'x', 
            label = 'y', 
            choices = levels(myDataSet$df$z),
            multiple = T
    )
})
```

Bounces back with:

> Error in output$myChoices <- renderUI({ : 
>     object 'output' not found

Obviously the problem is that within the `file.R` the variable `output` is not defined since this is a variable which is used in the shiny context. How would I tell `R` (or shiny) to treat all the variables as shiny defined variables (such as `output$whatever`, `input$something`, `reactive` etc). That seems crucial to me in order to break up the programme into smaller peaces.

Comment: don't have an answer for you, but you can have `x <- renderUI({ ...  })` in your file.R, and then use `output$mychoices <- x` within the server

Answer (score 1):

I'm using both source(local=TRUE) and sys.source to load the file into the proper environment, it seems to work:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    # From http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html
    output$text <- renderText({
        source('each_call.R', local=TRUE)
    })

    # Source in the file.R from the example in the question
    sys.source('file.R', envir=environment())
})
```

I didn't test it, but you might be able to use:

```
sourceRecursive <- function(path, env) {
    files <- list.files(path = path, pattern = "^.*[Rr]$", recursive = TRUE)
    for (f in files) sys.source(f, env)
}

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    session.env <- environment()
    sourceRecursive(path = ".", env = session.env)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `local=TRUE` in your call to source provided that `sourceRecursive` is in the right scope (maybe put it in server.R). See this documentation [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html)